# Python loop over excel file each rows to met condtion and get value from fist columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, filter

**I am new python DF, and I have an excel file two columns where I want to loop over its rows. codition if columns "amount" over its rows value equal zero, I would like to get sheft value each row from the first column and keep in list.

```
import pandas as pd**

    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    reuslt =[]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        amount = df.iloc[i,1]
        result.append(shelf)
    
    Example detial  excel file
    shelf  amount
    11        0
    13        1
    15        8
    18        0
    20        6
    22        0
    25        1`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate explicitly - Pandas gives you all the tools you need to easily search or filter rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'shelf': [11,13,15,18,20,22,25],
        'amount': [0,1,8,0,6,0,1]
    }
)

# get DataFrame onyl with "zero amount shelfs"
df_zero_shelfs = df[df['amount']==0]
df_zero_shelfs

##################
Output:

  shelf amount
0   11  0
3   18  0
5   22  0

##################

# cast zero amount shelfs IDs to list
list_zero_shelfs = list(df_zero_shelfs['shelf'].values)
list_zero_shelfs
##################
Output:

[11, 18, 22]
```

**[EDIT]**
If you really want to stick to for loop (not advised):

```py
result = []
for row in df.values:
    if row[1] == 0:
        result.append(row[0])
```

Comment: For loop is not advised in this case because pandas supports faster and easier ways of doing that but if you really want I added such example in my edited answer. 
Just please remember upvoting and marking my solution as the correct answer if it solves your problem, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you help  advise in case loop for ? because my amount   is always changed suddenly  then  check status " done", if done I will record  costid in amount2
    shelf  amount     status    costtid
    11        0             Done      
    13        1             unfill
    15        8             unfill
    18        0             Done
    20        6             unfill
    22        0             Done
    25        1`            unfill

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for here. I proposed a solution for your original question and later added a "dirty" for loop based on your follow up request but it seems like you keep changing your question. Make your mind please on what you want to achieve and state that clearly in your original question

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir,